# Bad result in Name Entity Recognition with BiLSTM - CRF

Tags: keras, deep-learning, named-entity-recognition

I have been trying to build a BiLSTM - CRF model (with word embeddings and POS information) to perform NER task. For some reasons, no matter what parameters i tried, and i have tried a lot, the highest f1 score my model can achieve is about 41.5% for Vietnamese and 35% for English (dataset is Conll2003).

I don't have any intention of aiming for state of the arts precision, just trying to build myself a NER model for learning purpose. But from the research papers that i have read, even the simplest BiLSTM model (no word embeddings) can achieve a f1 score over 70%.

The sequences are processed and padded by keras's Tokenizer:

```
tokenizer = Tokenizer(lower=False, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^`{|}~\t\n')
# Make dictionary mapping word to an integer.
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(untag_txt)
words_index = tokenizer.word_index

# Turn sentences into sequences
train_untag_txt = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_untag_txt)
test_untag_txt = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(test_untag_txt)

# Pad sentence sequences
train_untag_txt = pad_sequences(train_untag_txt, maxlen=50, padding='post', truncating='post')
test_untag_txt = pad_sequences(test_untag_txt, maxlen=50, padding='post', truncating='post')

# Pad tag sequences
train_ner_tags = np.array(pad_sequences(train_ner_tags, maxlen=50, padding='post', truncating='post', value=tag2id['OTHERS']))
test_ner_tags = np.array(pad_sequences(test_ner_tags, maxlen=50, padding='post', truncating='post', value=tag2id['OTHERS']))
```

My model:

```
model = Sequential([
      Embedding(len(words_index)+1, 218,  weights=[embedding_matrix], trainable=False),
      Dropout(0.4),
      Bidirectional(LSTM(256, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', return_sequences=True, 
                         bias_initializer='zeros', recurrent_dropout=0.4)),
      Dropout(0.4),
      Bidirectional(LSTM(256, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', return_sequences=True, 
                         bias_initializer='zeros', recurrent_dropout=0.4)),
      Dropout(0.4),
      Bidirectional(LSTM(256, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', return_sequences=True, 
                         bias_initializer='zeros', recurrent_dropout=0.4)),
      Dropout(0.4),
      Bidirectional(LSTM(256, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', return_sequences=True, 
                         bias_initializer='zeros', recurrent_dropout=0.4)),
      CRF(9, kernel_initializer='glorot_normal', sparse_target=True)
```

The paper in which i looked up f1 scores of different types of model:
https://www.aclweb.org/anthology/Q16-1026

Answer (score 0):

For those who are having the same problem, the solution to my case is removing all filter in the Tokenizer.

From: `tokenizer = Tokenizer(lower=False, filters='!"#$%&()*+,-./:;<=>?@[\\]^{|}~\t\n')`

To: `tokenizer = Tokenizer(lower=False, filters=[])`

Because i intended to use those speacial characters information and POS tags, i didn't remove them from the dataset. But when the Tokenizer transformed texts to sequences

```
train_untag_txt = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(train_untag_txt)
```

It filtered out all those characters, but their NER and POS tags still remain and got processed by the model. I'm guessing it created an unbalance in the data and label sets, where the words doesn't match their NER and POS tags correctly.